# Create daemon 'like' thread in java that can only be killed at certain safe points?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, shutdown

The code I've inherited is a server that spawns *many* different types of daemon threads that receive and respond to requests as they come in.  Obviously, this is dangerous and needs to be refactored away.  As it is now if the main program is halted while one of the daemons is servicing a request the thread could be killed midway through the request and leaving something in an inconsistent state.

However, there are quite a few threads spread through different areas of the code.  If I had to manually close every one of the threads when a shutdown is called, well it could be a bit of a pain to get logic flow perfect without missing some obscure daemon.

What I would like to do instead is to have a thread that is like a daemon thread, but I can mark or toggle some section of the thread as a critical section; which will complete the therad from being reaped until it completes.  While the daemon is blocking and waiting for requests it behaves like a daemon thread, doesn't prevent the VM from closing, and will be stopped immediately if the VM is shutting down.  However, while the thread is actively servicing a specific request (a fraction of the time the thread is active) the thread will *not* be killed until it completes and exits it’s critical section.  Once the thread finishes it's critical section it then becomes eligible to be killed.  Ideally when no more non-daemon threads are available the VM would  start it’s shut down process immediately, even if some daemons are still doing critical work, by reaping any daemon not in a critical state and then wait for each remaining 'daemon' to exit it's critical point so it could be killed.

Is there an easy way to get this behavior just by instantiating a Thread class (possibly one I write) or setting a Boolean, rather than having to explicitly write each thread to properly handle interrupts to behave like this?  I'm looking for a mostly idiot proof way so that if plugins, running in such a thread, are not written to handle interrupts perfectly the thread will still properly complete it's critical section and then exit when the VM is shutting down.

Comment: Ideally some dream-framework already implemnts this, but if not I'm not above implementing it; just to see if I can if nothing else (if it doesn't become so abstract as to cluttler my code).  To implement it I would need to capture the InterruptedException and tempoararily ignore it until I exit my critical state, then ....what? rethrow it?  exit my code?  The bigger question though is how would I make sure that my "smartDaemon" class *gets* the interupt, ie can I ensure that I see the interrupt even if the code in the thread doesn't propigate it perfectly?

Comment: Sounds like to you want to use interrupt().  When you interrupt a thread it only stops at "safe" points where the interrupt is checked, otherwise your thread runs until it does the check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, there are quite a few threads spread through different areas of the code. If I had to manually close every one of the threads when a shutdown is called, well it could be a bit of a pain to get logic flow perfect without missing some obscure daemon.

Unfortunately the best way to do this is as you imply.  You should have a `destroy()` method on the classes that fork threads so they can explicitly clean up after themselves.  But this does require someone calling those destroy methods when the application is terminating.

> What I would like to do instead is to have a thread that is like a daemon thread, but has a certain critical section where it cannot be killed until it completes (or maybe times out if it takes too long?).

There is nothing in the Java threads that allows this behavior.  Either a thread is daemon or it is not and this is set *before* the thread starts.

> Is there an easy way to get this behavior just by instantiating a class or setting a Boolean

I think you are on to something here.  I would have a `ThreadUtils` class with a `volatile boolean shutdown` field.

```
 public class ThreadUtils {
     private static volatile boolean shutdown = false;
     /** called by main when the application is shutting down */
     public static void shutdown() {
         shutdown = true;
     }
     /** used by the various non-daemon threads to test for shutdown */
     public static boolean isShutdown() {
         return shutdown;
     }
 }
```

You main program would set the shutdown flag to true and then all of your threads would need to check this boolean in their code:

```
 // we can test for shutdown only at "appropriate" points in the thread
 while (!ThreadUtils.isShutdown()) {
     ...
     // we are not ready to be killed here
     ...
 }
```

Something like this pattern, although a bit gross, sounds like it fulfills your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to improving last answer by @Gray.

You can maintain a counter of currently running threads. Every new thread starting will increment this counter and every thread completing `run()` will decrement it. Then you can add a shutdown hook in your main thread by using API `Runtime.addShutdownHook()` . When java process is signaled to quit, this hook will set the condition for global flag `ThreadUtils.isShutdown()` to true and wait for all running threads to complete work and die naturally when all threads have exited.

To prevent indefinite wait, you can have a timeout inside shutdown hook's `run()` method. If timeout occurred, `run()` will terminate immediately resulting in all daemon threads to terminate too.

Comment: yes, I think this will work, though I don't know rather it's worth the extra abstraction for this particular project (not everyone working on the team is as experienced as a programer and I need to avoid doing anything too fancy that will confuse them).  However, I'm rally curious about implemnting something like this in my down time; as a utility with a factory model that abstracts and hides this logic from end-users.  Though I don't know what one would do if one of these 'daemons' started a non-daemon while in process of shutting down...

Answer (score 0):

So all these daemon threads are event loops processing requests. What if you simply send a shutdown request to all of them, so they can exit cooperatively. Each thread probably has an ad hoc way of polling request from somewhere, so you'll need to refactor them a little.